# _underscore templating - loading templates from external files

Tags: javascript, templates, dom, underscore.js

I've seen a few long winded answers to how to load templates for rendering in respect of the _underscore templates utility and the like. What I've got below works:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'template.tmp',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
        $('html').append(data);
    }
});
```

The code sits after jquery is loaded but before any scripts using the templates. Would this be ok or is there a reason why it wouldn't be a good idea to load templates like this? The templates.tmp file has templates within

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpId"></script>
```

tags. They seem to get loaded into the DOM pretty much instantly. I'm prepared to be criticised for this implementation, but I'd just like to know why. The only thing I can think of is perhaps some processing if "error:" gets called instead of "success:". Thx.

Comment: Since `$.ajax()` is asynchronous, you could run into the situation where the code that uses those templates is run *before* the templates are loaded into the DOM. Also, any reason why not to include the templates in your main HTML to begin with?

Comment: @robertklep I suppose I could put a check in the template related functions for the elements first with a setInterval to check they're in the DOM, so now the code starts getting longer. It's a very valid point though and should be checked for. As for why. I'm reading everywhere that a modular approach is best practice.

Comment: well, a modular approach is recommendable, but once you have to start using `setInterval` to check for the availability of templates in the DOM you should wonder if it's the correct approach in this use case :) Perhaps the code that renders the templates could demand-load them (and store them somewhere if they need to render them repeatedly)? ([perhaps useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7542468/893780))

Comment: Maybe. If I know it's likely they're going to be used, loading them in advance asynchronously and checking for their presence is going to be easier on the user.

Comment: True, that's why I would opt for including them in the HTML to begin with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to produce my own OO based solution. This is the constructor:

```
var TemplateLoader = function(templatePath) {
    this.template = templatePath;
    this.loaded = false;
    this.error = false;
}
```

And these are the methods:

```
TemplateLoader.prototype.setReady = function (state) {
    this.loaded = state;
}
TemplateLoader.prototype.setError = function (state) {
    this.error = state;
}
TemplateLoader.prototype.isReady = function () {
    return this.loaded;
}
TemplateLoader.prototype.isError = function () {
    return this.error;
}
TemplateLoader.prototype.loadTemplate = function() {
        templateLoader = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.template,
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {
                $('html').append(data);
                templateLoader.setReady(true);
            },
            error: function() {
                templateLoader.setError(true);
            }
        });
}
```

And this is how to use it:

```
templateLoader = new TemplateLoader('template.tmpl');
templateLoader.loadTemplate();
```

And to check the template has loaded:

```
templateLoader.isReady() //true for loaded
templateLoader.isError() //true for error loading template, eg. template doesn't exist
```

Again, I'd appreciate any feedback on issues anyone could see with this code. How about checking for the DOM object appended to the HTML. Worthwhile?